# Duplicates that are a new view of an old question

Tags: discussion

This one [Plumber drilled through exterior 2x4s - that's bad, right?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/234155/plumber-drilled-through-exterior-2x4s-thats-bad-right)
I kind of like, because it's new detailed pictures of an old problem.

It's like the *answer* is common but the *question* is unique to the situation and valuable.

What do people think?

Comment: Does the answer to the old question also answer this one? If so, they are duplicates. Closing them as such sends everybody to the same set of answers, instead of splitting the audience (and the content, and the moderation) across multiple places for no reason.